# Replace a function of wordpress parent theme inside functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

There is not a specific answer for this exact issue so i am going to try this.

So in the parent theme of a wordpress website there is a php file named `helpers-icons.php`. The exact path for this file is `/wp-content/themes/parent/inc/helpers/helpers-icons.php`, and the content of that file is

```
function get_flatsome_icon($name, $size = null) {
  if($size) $size = 'style="font-size:'.$size.';"';
  return '<i class="'.$name.'" '.$size.'></i>';
}
```

This file is then inlcuded in `functions.php` of that parent theme.

Now i want to override a function inside and being more specific, just this line of code
`return '<i class="'.$name.'" '.$size.'></i>';` to `return '<span class="'.$name.'" '.$size.'></span>';`

how could i do that on child theme without messing with the php files of parent?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT 2**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - Different Approach**

You can copy the file /inc/helpers/helpers-icons.php into your child theme (keep the folder structure - e.g. /child-theme/inc/helpers/helpers-icons.php). That way it will be called instead of the original file and you can change the function there.

**(Original Answer) Removing Functions From Hooks:**

You’ll need to de-hook the parent function and hook your child theme function instead by using `remove_action()` and `remove_filter()`.

The one you use will depend on whether the function is attached to an action hook or filter hook in the parent theme.

To remove a function, use:

```
remove_action( 'init', 'parent_function' );
```

However, this won’t work on its own, you will need to attach this function to a hook which will fire after the hook which the parent theme function is attached to. This is because you can’t remove the action before it’s been fired.

```
function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_action( 'init', 'parent_function', [priority level] );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'child_remove_parent_function' );
```

NOTE: If the parent_function() was loaded using a priority level, you have to unloaded by stating the same level as well. That’s why [priority level] is in square brackets.

As you may imagine, wp-loaded is a hook that comes after init, so `remove_action()` can really remove the parent_function() that was loaded to init.

Now you’re free to write whatever new function you’d like.

```
function child_function() {
    // your function
}
add_action( 'init', 'child_function' );
```

Source and further reading: https://obsessive-coffee-disorder.com/how-to-override-parent-theme-functions-in-wordpress/

Comment: Which error is that? You didn't mention an error on the original post

Comment: I edited the original post with a screenshot

Comment: Try to add `add_action( 'init', 'get_flatsome_icon' );`

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternative solution, I hope it helps